# How do i configure my git hooks (post-receive) and my nginx server and my ununtu server (16.04) to upload my laravel6 application

Tags: laravel, git, nginx-config

I followed this guide *one by one*:

https://www.axfon.com/install-laravel-5-7-php-7-3-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/

I tried to set up git hooks so I can just deploy my own application instead of this fresh install.

I tried to do it following this guide (partly):

**I am using php7.3 Ubuntu 16.04 Server and Laravel 6**

https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/

This was the commands I tried:

```
sudo chown -R reniar var
sudo chogrp -R reniar var
```

This I had to do so I could perform the mkdir repo step ...

```
cd /var
mkdir repo && cd repo

mkdir site.git && cd site.git
git init --bare

cd /hooks
sudo vim post-receive
```

this is how my post-receive looks without the "

```
"#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/test --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

(obviously I want my Laravel-App to live inside the "test" dir)

my nginx config looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/test/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name dev.test.com;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

then

```
exit

cd Sites/blog

git remote add production ssh://root@example.com/var/repo/site.git

git push production master
```

login to webserver again

```
cd /var/www/laravel
ls
```

-> confirms that the test folder now contains my laravel app

```
composer install --no-dev

sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage
```

my folders and permissions on my webserver look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 reniar reniar 4096 Sep 26 12:23 www/
drwxrwxr-x 2 reniar reniar 4096 Sep 26 15:29 test/
drwxr-xr-x  15 reniar reniar  4096 Sep 26 14:50 var/
drwxrwxr-x  3 reniar reniar 4096 Sep 26 14:50 repo/
drwxrwxr-x  7 reniar reniar 4096 Sep 26 14:57 site.git/
drwxrwxr-x 2 reniar reniar 4096 Sep 26 15:46 hooks/
```

now my laravelapp should be able to send a laravel custom message to me but instead I just receive a blank white page ...

I am on this problem since two days and really need some help.

---

MY MAIN QUESTIONS ARE:

**1. HOW DO I GET MY APP ON MY SERVER WITH GIT?**

**2. IS THERE A BETTER MORE EASY WAY THAN GIT?**

**3. HOW DO I UPLOAD CHANGES TO MY APP ALSO WITH GIT?**

---

PS: no i *don't* want to use a *payed service*, I want to do everything on my own

This is my first post on Stackoverflow.

be gentle :D

Comment: Since it's a laravel deploy, i would suggest you to check https://deployer.org/ out ...

Comment: WoW I have no idea how that works can you explain me a little bit?

Comment: Hi there! Just follow their documentation, it's pretty straight forward, and you have an specific recipe for laravel